# How to identify a sybase db file (how to know which software which version)

Tags: sql-server, sybase, sqlanywhere

i have a sybase database *.DB file 
i dont know which software created it and which version
i want to know which sybase engine is used and which version
and is the version of the engine related to spesific software
i mean can i use any client with this database engine

also i want to know a brief steps to how to install the sybase engine and the client software and restore the database created from the DB file

Sorry for these many questions as i am a MS SQL developer but i need to open this sybase DB and convert it to MS SQL :(

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.db is typically used by Sybase SQL Anywhere, and Sybase IQ.  Since you are tasked with converting it to MS SQLServer, it's a safe bet that the file is from SQL Anywhere.

You can find out about [installing, and upgrading .db files here](http://dcx.sybase.com/1101/en/sachanges_en11/unloading-reloading-upgrading-newjasper.html)

Once you have the software installed, and the database running, you can use **[Sybase Central](http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbadmin_en11/scover.html)**, the management GUI, or **[dbunload](http://dcx.sybase.com/1100/en/dbadmin_en11/dbunload.html)** on the command line to extract the DDL you need to build your MS SQLServer Environment.

Comment: thx i tried it but failed with theses messages window

dbunload -v -c "UID=dba;PWD=***;DBF=C:\Documents and Settings\mariam\Desktop\asmaaaa.DB" -an "C:\Documents and Settings\mariam\Desktop\NewDatabase.db" -ap 4096 -ea None -ii -sa -so _sc154244321
Connecting and initializing
***** SQL error: Unable to start database server: Server fatal error
The database 'C:\Documents and Settings\mariam\Desktop\asmaaaa.DB' could not be unloaded.
The database 'C:\Documents and Settings\mariam\Desktop\asmaaaa.DB' could not be unloaded.

Comment: Have you successfully run the database?  I would make sure you can access the database (via isql or Sybase Central), before you attempt to run dbunload.